# Coffee color mystery

Tags: visible-light, condensed-matter, scattering

I'm sure all coffee drinkers have come across this at some point or another, namely the following scenario:

When coffee drops are being poored into a glass from a coffee machine, the apparent color is light brown and well transparent. But as the drops rejoin in the glass, the color starts turning darker and darker towards the expected black. I'm trying to understand the physics behind this seemingly simple scenario.

I imagine that this is very much analogous to how we explain the white color of milk, namely the type of light scattering that takes place: milk is an emulsion of fat and water. Fat being hydrophobic, we can only mix the two by making the size of oil drops very small to minimise the surface tension between the two fluids, and ultimately reach some form of equilibrium (i.e. a long time required for the two to demix). The white color then results from the scattering of light by the fat droplets of the emulsion, namely the average spacing of these droplets is such that almost all wavelengths can be reflected. I admit this is overly simplified.

Now if we want to apply a similar line of reasoning to explain the coloring of coffee, we'd have to express things in terms of the properties of the coloidal dispersion of the milled coffee beans in water. I guess we can assume the dispersion to be homogeneous because in hot coffee the Brownian motion is dominant compared to the gravitational force.

- Could the final black color just be due to the larger volume? That is, the scattered light undergoes many more scatterings before it reaches our eyes, compared to the scattering taking place in a single droplet?
- Or rather, could it be that the interaction of colloidal particles changes in the bulk (which in turn changes the density of the dispersed coilloidal particles)?

Comment: I doubt your second possibility is the case. A single droplet of coffee _is_ the bulk, it already contains many many atoms. It's unlikely that $10^21$ atoms would behave differently than $10^22$.

Comment: Some time ago a question came up about why there is a froth on tea, (NOT coffee).  I did a lot of research to answer the question, all based, of course around coffee not tea.  Posted the answer and then deleted it.  Point is that I learnt a lot about the significant  role of Carbon Dioxide as regards coffee, so possibly you could research that.

Comment: @knzhou I have this feeling as well. But I thought maybe from the point of view of classical nucleation theory, the two cases (droplet vs bulk) remain well distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as the drops rejoin in the glass, the color starts turning darker and darker towards the expected black

I'm inclined to think it's simply a matter of the amount of material the light must pass through.

A drop is a small amount of liquid to pass through compared to an entire glass.  The intensity of light is reduced simply by absorption, but there's so much more of the fluid to pass through that the intensity is reduced to such a low level is appears black.

The liquid doesn't change, but the amount of it the light must pass through does.

Comment: Very plausible. This is very close to the first explanation I had imagined (larger volume).